# Locationlistener is null

Tags: android, google-maps, android-volley, locationlistener

The error comes because of the location listener is null.I put the location listener in the `JsonObjectRequest` of volley library.
my code is

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 500, 1, mLocationListener);

    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        UiSettings uiSettings=mMap.getUiSettings();
        uiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, loginUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {
                    JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("hi");
                    retid= new String[ja.length()];
                    retph= new String[ja.length()];
                    retname=new String[ja.length()];
                    retlat= new Double[ja.length()];
                    retlong= new Double[ja.length()];
                    for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject=ja.getJSONObject(i);
                        if(!(jsonObject.getString("retailer_loc_lat").equals("0")&&jsonObject.getString("retailer_loc_long").equals("0"))) {
                            retid[i] = jsonObject.getString("retailer_id") + "";
                            retname[i] = jsonObject.getString("retailer_first_name") + " " + jsonObject.getString("retailer_last_name");
                            retlat[i] = Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString("retailer_loc_lat"));
                            retlong[i] = Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString("retailer_loc_long"));
                            retph[i] = "Phone:" + jsonObject.getString("retailer_ph_no");

                        }
                    }

                   mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
                                    for(int j=0;j<retid.length;j++){
                                        if(almostEqual(retlat[j],location.getLatitude(),.5)&&almostEqual(retlong[j],location.getLatitude(),.5)){
                                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(retlat[j], retlong[j])).title(retname[j]).snippet(retph[j]).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_pin_96)));
                                        }
                                    }

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                                }
                            };


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    }
```

my log cat

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid listener: null
                                                                     at android.location.LocationManager.checkListener(LocationManager.java:1606)
                                                                     at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:426)
```

**The main reason is that the location manager cant get the location listener in
the `JsonObjectRequest`. Please help.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);` is an aysnchronous non-blocking call.
Hence
`mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 500, 1, mLocationListener);`
gets executed before you get `onMapReady()` callback.
Now since  `mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 500, 1, mLocationListener);`  gets executed before  `onMapReady()` , `mLocationListener` is null since you haven't initialized it before. And that's why you get Exception.

Comment: I guess you can put mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates() in onMapReady() . Also add null check in onCreate().

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    ...
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, loginUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                ...
                mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
                    ...
                };
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 500, 1, mLocationListener);
                ...
```